# Ad banner doesn't show

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to integrate AdMob into my Unity game. I added the Google AdMob package  and put the ad script into a new game object. My game is 3d and my ad doesn't show. I used 2 script to see which works and neither appear. I want it for iOS, but when I play the game in Xcode, it starts but without any ads.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdsBanner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

#if UNITY_IOS
        string appId = "ca-app-pub-5414609211143331~4701275804";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
       string appId= "ca-app-pub-5414609211143331~4701275804" ;

#else
        string appId = "" ; 
#endif

        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
        RequestBanner();
    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {

#if UNITY_IOS
        string bannerUnitId = "ca-app-pub-5414609211143331/4318132422";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
       string bannerUnitId= "ca-app-pub-5414609211143331/4318132422" ;

#else
        string bannerUnitId = "" ; 
#endif
        bannerView = new BannerView(bannerUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdsScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        showBannerAd();
    }

    private void showBannerAd()
    {
        string adID = "ca-app-pub-5414609211143331/4318132422";

        //***For Testing in the Device***
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
       .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)       // Simulator.
       .AddTestDevice("5414609211143331~4701275804s")  // My test device.
       .Build();

        //***For Production When Submit App***
        //AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        BannerView bannerAd = new BannerView(adID, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
        bannerAd.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added debug statements to show that you're pulling ad banners? If you have the data, is the problem displaying the banner?

Comment: I don't know if I have to add something to the settings... Like I know that for android you need to change AndroidManifest , to add the meta data , but I don't know for iOS if I need to do something more than add a script to a free game object in the project

Comment: Pro tip: When you publish your game add a proper 'privacy policy' page where it is mentioned that you 'collect' the phone IDs. One of my games was stip down from Google Play because of this xaxa.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with your code. My development environment is as follows:

Xcode10.2.1

Unity2018.3.11f1

Combined with the official documentation steps https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start?hl=zh-US operations are summarized below:

1.The code you give needs to add some debug code, as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

2.Link the AdsBanner script to the game scene, as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

3.Then build and run, build Player Settings is as follows screenshot.
[image]

4.In the Xcode console, look at the logs and look for the AdsBanner keyword, as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

I have the same problem as you, the advertisement does not come out, my analysis is like this:

1.Network problems, because I am in China, I use a different network than you, I change the network (the result is still the same problem, this solution is not, not the network).

2.Admob related ID problem, I created a new app and a banner ad id with my AdMob account, the result is still the same problem, then I modify its banner ad id configuration, the problem remains, There is a setting associated with the AppStore app link in the app, I understand that its association is irrevocable, I have not tried, if you have not configured, you can try to associate.

3.In exchange for the relevant ID, I follow the https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/test-ads?hl=zh-CN guidelines, use the official recommended test ID to test, the results banner ads come out, indicating that the code integration is not problem.

Finally, my advice is:

1.Check your app and banner ad ID settings and set up the required configuration, such as the AppStore app association I mentioned earlier.

2.Create a new banner ad id and wait a few hours before testing, which may be delayed.

3.Try different networks,Such as cellular networks and WI-FI.

There are still problems to discuss together, I am very interested in this issue.